# How to run vim terminal with QProcess

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qprocess

I want to do the "vim" command, The "vim" command is used to open a new editor in linux. "setup.csh" open file "vi" editör with QProcess. I would like to run this command using gui.

linux terminal command:"vim /home/intern2/elif/Project/setup.csh" .How can I run this command gui

I wrote the following commands in Qt, but it did not work using QProcess.

```
QProcess *process1=new QProcess(this);
process1->start("vim" , QStringList() <<"/home/intern2/elif/Project/setup.csh");
process1->waitForBytesWritten();
process1->waitForFinished();
ui->textEdit_3->append(process1->readAllStandardOutput());
```

Unfortunately, I gave the following error message

Error Message:

```
Warning: Output is not a terminal
Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

Comment: do you want to open a new Terminal window? If so, you need to actually specify the terminal application like `process1->start("xterm" , QStringList() <<"-e" << "vim"<< "/home/intern2/elif/Project/setup.csh");`. If you want the file contents you should use `cat` instead (or actually you should just open the file with a `QFile`, opening shell programs behind a GUI should be treated with care), so `process1->start("cat" , QStringList() <<"/home/intern2/elif/Project/setup.csh");`?

Comment: Thank you, I worked as I wanted @PeterT

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this:

```
QProcess* process = new QProcess();
qint64* processId = new qint64();
process->startDetached("/usr/bin/vim", QStringList(), QString(), processId);

// Wait for process to be closed by user (kill()
// does not actually kill the process, but tests if it exists)
while (kill(*processId, 0) == 0) {}

// Done
delete processId;
delete process;
```

Don't forget to add `#include <signal.h>` for the `kill()` function.